# Album Artwork Add Fail

Tags: itunes

I can't add album artwork to particular albums in my itunes library even if the file is 'read and write' and MP3 Audio... Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by "can't"? Do you get an error message? How are you trying to add the artwork?

Comment: Also, you may want to add the version of iTunes you're running. While it's implied that you're talking about a PC/Mac (we don't know which), iTunes itself has changed greatly over the years and we have no way of knowing what version you're using.

Comment: I use Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.16, iTunes version 12.5.5.5. There's no error message. I apply the artwork through "Get info" and 'add artwork' that is saved to my finder folder. Once 'okayed' the artwork doesn't appear, neither if I close and reopen iTunes. The image file is JPEG.